# How do I get an interactive session using Slurm?

Tags: slurm

I found references to `srun --pty bash -i` (see https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#prompt) but when I run that on my cluster it exits immediately.

```
$ srun --pty bash -i
$ squeue
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
               1  team     bash schmmd  R       0:02      1 team-server1
```

I can get an interactive session with `srun bash`, but I don't have a shell prompt (e.g. `$`) and my session just looks like the following:

```
$ srun bash
ls
miniconda3
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
test
```

Is something misconfigured on my installation or should I be running a different command?

```
$ srun --version
slurm 19.05.0
```

Comment: Well--the problem was pretty stupid.  I was running `srun` from one of the machines on the cluster--and it was allocating the same machine!  I didn't notice that it was doing anything because my prompt didn't change (it had the same server name) but I validated it was working with `-w` and specifying another machine.

Comment: You should make that comment an answer. For your question, I think it is a better solution than salloc.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `salloc` and the requirements for your job. It will forward you to a new session prompt with the requested resources.

For instance:

```
salloc -N1
```

to request one node.

Comment: Good to know about `salloc`, but it still runs the job asynchronously (it detaches immediately).

Comment: AFAIK `salloc` returns a prompt and it is alive until you `exit`.

Comment: After some investigation, `salloc` does something a bit different.  It allocates a node to run your job, but the terminal you have is still on the original machine.  Within an `salloc` session though, all `srun` commands will run on the allocated node.